# How to createa a vector which contain int and strings?

Tags: c++

I would like to define a vector of `object` type and put there ints and strings

like this

```
std::vector<object> arr;
arr.push_back(4);
arr.push_back("HELLO");
```

There is no such type as `object` in c++

So, how can I achieve it?

Comment: `std::vector<std::variant<int, std::string>>` would be an option

Comment: What are you going to be doing with these integers and strings?

Comment: are you looking for `Object` like Java has one? In C++ there is no base of all objects, but there other types that you can use for your `std::vector<object>`.

Comment: failing [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) there is always the option of [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for vector of multiple data types. You may use

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, std::string>> arr;
```

```
std::vector<std::any> arr;
```

1. std::variant<int, std::string> (C++17) - The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union. For example
   `std::variant<int, std::string> tst;`

Retrieve the value using - `std::get<int>(tst)`

Check the type using `tst.index() - in our case 0 is int and 1 is std::string`

See here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

2. std::any (C++17) - The class any describes a type-safe container for single values of any copy constructible type. For example

`std::any tst=0;`

`tst.type().name() - gives i in this case`

`std::any_cast<int>(tst) - gives the int value`

See here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any